# Equivalent of SelfReferenceProperty in NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Looking at the [NDB Cheat Sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic) i see that I've been doing it 'correctly' but 
when using this code:

```
class Chapter(ndb.Model):
    parentID = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Chapter)
```

I get this error

```
NameError: name 'Chapter' is not defined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NDB properties page [notes:](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties)

> Optional keyword argument: kind=kind, to require that keys assigned to this property always have the indicated kind. May be a string or a Model subclass.

So try it in quotes?

```
parentID = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Chapter')
```

On the NDB cheat sheet it does actually show the example in quotes, so perhaps that's just the way to do it.

```
ndb.KeyProperty(kind='ThisModelClass')
```

Comment: quotes worked (facepalm). I'm going to use this to create subchapters. Chapter 1.1 will have as father chapter 1